# Плюсы и минусы создания сервера на своем компьютере

Tags: сервер, хостинг

Не могу найти хорошего хостинга, тот дорогой, а тот не подходит. Решил рискнуть поставить на компьютер сервер, не могли бы вы написать плюсы и минусы этой затеи.

Comment: А что ты имеешь в виду, когда говоришь, что "рискну поставить на компьютер, сервер"?

Comment: мне говорили, если плохая защита, то могут запросто тебя почистить или т.п.

Comment: О чем ты говоришь? Я не совсем понимаю.. При чем тут защита от чего либо и твой сервер? И что именно ты можешь почистить?

Comment: @dobermann Мне казалось что ТС тупит...хм...моё мнение поменялось...

ps. харе тупить :)

Comment: Как вариант в качестве сервера можно купить одноплатный комп, не шумит, электричества потребляет мало, да и сам по себе стоит не сильно дорого.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Плюсы:

- Ты сам себе хозяин.
- Много места для твоих проектов.

Минусы:

- Постоянный шум компьютера.
- Расходы на электричество.
- Убиваешь свое железо.
- Очень затратно.
- Нужно постоянно мониторить, обслуживать сервер.
- Постоянный онлайн, нужны средства на оплату трафика (если он не безлимитный)

Я бы не советовал заниматься данным мазохизмом, не пожалей пару баксов и возьми себе нормальный хостинг, меньше геморроя будет. Я бы посоветовал jino.ru. В любом случае это обойдется тебе дешевле, чем свой сервер. И я сомневаюсь что ты будешь использовать всю мощь своего сервера.

Comment: Ну, сервер можно выгодно приобрести и б/у который будет полностью подходить под твои нужды, и при этом (в долгосрочной перспективе) будет намного дешевле любого из хостингов.

Comment: Все-равно не окупится, разве что только взять себе на сервер еще несколько клиентов.

Comment: Окупится, в зависимости от того, какой будет проект.

Comment: @Dobermann, Если автор пишет что ищет хостинг:
> Не могу найти гуд хостинг

Так зачем ему ресурсы целого сервера? Понятно что у него там не очень большой проект, если он ищет именно хостинг.

Comment: Ты сам себе хозяин это не сказать ничего. Ради этого плюса можно пойти на любые жертвы.

Да и имея свой сервак ты можешь думать о чем-то масштабном без вложения огромных средств, что естественно тоже немаловажно.

@Йода - выделеный сервер снимать это не не так уж и дорого а - дорого.

Единичные затраты на бесперебойник - решают проблему электричества.
По поводу поддержки - зависит от того у кого он стоит.

По поводу неприемлим для серьезных проэктов - бред.

Естественно речь идет не о домашнем интернет канале.

И да - никакой хостинг не заменит своего сервера, надо понимаьть разницу каГбы

Comment: Правда что касается ТСа - лучше забыть об этом сразу. Для того чотбы держать свой серв нужныт большие знания, много времени ну и, естественно, финансовые вложения (пускай и в пределах разумного но тем не менее)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, чо, опять похоливарим? :D

> Ты сам себе хозяин это не сказать ничего

Можно было выписать из этой фразы кучу плюсов, но у меня было мало времени, да и не хотелось напрягать мозг 1 января.

> Да и имея свой сервак ты можешь думать о чем-то масштабном без вложения огромных средств, что естественно тоже немаловажно.

На сколько я понял у автора не масштабный проект, раз уж он искал хостинг(!). Сомневаюсь что это будет "без вложения огромных средств", как раз таки наоборот.

> И да - никакой хостинг не заменит своего сервера, надо понимаьть разницу каГбы 

Не всегда сервер рулит.

Comment: Я писал всегда?

Отвечал я не конкретно ТСу а на вопрос **в общем смысле**.

Кишка тонка со мной холиварить, в этом вопросе так точно.

И кстати - сервер рулит всегда, в прямых руках разумеется и для тех кто в танке - на сервере КагБы хостинги и подымают, но на хостинге ты **всегда** в чем-то ограничен, на своем личном сервере - естественно нет.

В который раз понимаю что ни с чем серьезным вы не работали(тогда враппер mysql_query приводит к понижению производительности, теперь это...)

Comment: Я не злой, @Elime - повторюсь еще раз:

**Отвечал я не конкретно ТСу а на вопрос в общем смысле.**

Далее я написал разьянения конкретно для ТСа, в чем проблема то?

Answer (score 3):

Плюсы имеются при выполнении двух условий:

- если есть ненужный компьютер,
- если есть бесплатный быстрый интернет.

Минусы:

- никакой поддержки (владелец уехал в отпуск - сервер упал),
- никакой надежности (отключили электричество в подъезде, сервер упал),
- никакой скорости (обычная домовая сеть),
- это не так уж и дешево (посчитайте, сколько стоит электричество и трафик).

Для более-менее серьезных проектов домашний сервер неприемлим из-за вышеуказанных минусов. Хороших хостингов, вообще говоря, много.

Comment: и вам спасибо =)

Answer (score 2):

Во всяком случае, домашний сервер - это замечательный способ стать хорошим сисадмином.

Comment: Возможно , но как написали выше это больше мазахизм...

Comment: Любой процесс обучения (особенно самообучения) в чем-то отдает мазОхизмом

Comment: Если у автора стоит задача стать сисадмином, сделать свой сервер было бы полезно.

Comment: Ага, только начинать надо со снесения windows, прощанием с играми и приветствия linux...

Comment: AlexWindHope, а я после месяца использования linux, сегодня вернулся на windows (да здравствуйте игры! :D). Юзал ubuntu, какая-то она не доделанная..

Comment: А зачем пересаживался то, от скуки?

Да и ты не собираешся свой сервак подымать, а подымать сервак на Windows, извольте - ужас летящий на крыльях ночи.

Лично мне (и многим моим колегам) банально удобнее и приятнее вести разработку под linux'ом.

Да и, что немаловажно - терминал в линухе то что нужно, от виндовского убожества у меня сразу-дже напрашивается рвотные рефлекс. Да, собственно, от любого виндовского убожества xD

Но тут не суть, если кому интересно - винда у меня стоит. Ради фотошопа и скайрима :DDD

Comment: @AlexWindHope

>А зачем пересаживался то, от скуки?

Ага.

На винде вообще нету надобности пользоваться терминалом

> Ради фотошопа и скайрима :DDD
одной из причин возвращения на винду, был фотошоп, ну и кс :D

Ну серв я не подымал ни на винде ни на лине, мне это не нужно, линь использовал чисто в ознакомительных целях.

Comment: Если нужен рабочий домашний сервер, то придется выделить отдельную машину, а установить - линукс или какой-нибудь бсд,тут уж никуда не денешься. 

Если просто учиться сисадминству, то все равно от линей никуда не денешься. Можно поставить на одну машину с виндой (если последняя очень нужна) и разгружать ту или иную систему. Можно поставить под виртуальную машину.

Comment: ответ человека умудренного опытом! :)

Answer (score 0):

Если не подходят хостинги, так можно же виртуальный сервер арендовать, если у буржуйской компании, то это не сильно дорого. Я думаю дешевле обойдётся, чем именно свой домашний  сервер.